# Lost 3 rep to a user being removed

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-accounts

My question is: what activity could I have done to gain 3 rep to be lost when the user left?

Comment: Solving $\ 10k + 5n - 2m = 3\ $ is not difficult. Keep your math hat on while on meta.

Answer (score 10):

Upvotes on questions give +5 reputation. Downvotes give -2 reputation.

Therefore, a likely explanation is that the user upvoted one of your questions and downvoted another of your posts.

Answer (score 3):

You did nothing.

Some user upvoted one of your questions, and downvoted one of your posts, neither of which was marked as Community Wiki.

When the user account was removed, the votes were nullified and the reputation they gave you (positive or negative) was removed. If it makes you feel any better, I'd lost 28 points yesterday from a user removal, possibly the same user.

Comment: Those 28 points are going to hurt you a lot ;)

Comment: Well, you know... :-)